How to Move/drag a WinUI 3 Window with no title bar
I want to have a winUI 3 Window with no title bar and draggable from his entire client area.
Like I used to do in Winforms and WPF, I tried using a win32 call (the "sendMeaasge") (see code below). But it seems to be broken in WinUI 3 because it doesn't drag the window on the pointer pressed but only when the pointer is released.
below is the code using the "sendMessage" win32 api call. when using this, the window is moved only when the pointer is released.
public sealed partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        //Remove the title bar
        (AppWindow?.Presenter as OverlappedPresenter)?.SetBorderAndTitleBar(false, false);
        Content = new Grid() { Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent) };
        this.Content.PointerPressed += MainWindow_PointerPressed;
    }

    private void MainWindow_PointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ReleaseCapture();
        var hwnd = WinRT.Interop.WindowNative.GetWindowHandle(this);
        SendMessage(hwnd, WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN, (IntPtr)HTCAPTION, IntPtr.Zero);
    }

    private const int WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN = 0xA1;
    private const int HTCAPTION = 0x2;

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool ReleaseCapture();
}

I also try using the pointerPressed, pointerMoved and pointerReleased and moving the window manually but is really not smooth enough.
I would like the mouse and touch to both work, so that is why I don't want to use the position of the cursor to move the window.

You need to specify which regions are interactive to ensure that your interactive elements receive user input while still allowing users to move your window around. I suggest you could refer to the Doc:Interactive content

Ok thank you. It's a lot of work but totally doable. Thanks again.

You can try making the Window content as a TitleBar:
<Window
    x:Class="WinUIApp.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="using:WinUIApp4"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Frame
        x:Name="ContentFrame"
        Background="Transparent">
        <TextBlock Text="Your content here..." />
    </Frame>

</Window>

public sealed partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        CustomizeWindow();
    }

    private void CustomizeWindow()
    {
        if (AppWindow?.Presenter is not OverlappedPresenter presenter)
        {
            return;
        }

        presenter.SetBorderAndTitleBar(hasBorder: false, hasTitleBar: false);
        ExtendsContentIntoTitleBar = true;
        SetTitleBar(this.ContentFrame);
    }
}


Thank you for you're reply. I already tried that one, but then it becomes extemely diffcult to even make a button clickable. I will have to customize the window if I want a control to receive events.

@yvannoume I am not answerer but SetTitleBar(this.ContentFrame) does the trick. See Window.SetTitleBar

@emoacht Like I said in my previous comment, by using 'SetTitleBar(this.ContentFrame)', I can't receive any events like a click. For example, try to put a button in the window to see what I mean. You won't be able to click the button.

Why don't you divide the window into area to accept mouse down to drag and other area for usual mouse event?

Ok thank you, I can indeed do that. I was just hoping to have the same behaviour as with the "SendMessage" win32 call.
